# big engian и little engian

Tags: c++, c

например есть число `0xaabbccdd` это 4 байтное число. я так понимаю это вроде как big engian, тогда в little engian оно будет иметь вид `0xbbaaddcc`? мне надо узнать как выглядит число в двух engian. и я не помню, но intel это же little engian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

4-х байтное число `0x12345678` в литтл эндиан (little endian) будет уложено в памяти слева направо как байты `0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12`. В биг эндиан (big endian) будут в памяти байты `0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78`.

В Intel используется little endian.

Какое бы по размеру число не было, 2-х байтное (uint16_t) или 4-х байтное (uint32_t) или 8-байтное (uint64_t), во всех случаях little endian укладывает его в памяти слева направо начиная с младших разрядов числа и под ряд до старших разрядов числа, а big endian укладывает ровно в противоположном порядке, т.е. big endian это обратный порядок байт порядка little endian.

Т.е. 2х-байтное `0x1234` в памяти little endian это `0x34, 0x12`, пример 4х-байтного привёл в начале, 8-байтное `0x123456789ABCDEF0` в little endian будет в памяти `0xF0, 0xDE, 0xBC, 0x9A, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12`.

Дословно с английского little endian означает "с малого конца", т.е. означает что в памяти байты начинаются с младших (малых) разрядов числа. Соответственно big endian означает "с большого конца", т.е. байты в памяти начинаются со старших (больших) разрядов числа.

В русском endianness называют "порядок байт".

Comment: добавлю, что сами английские термины «big/little endian» — это отсылка к тупо/остроконечникам из «Путешествий Гуливера» Свифта...

Comment: *`"видимо означает что в памяти байты..."`* -- именно так. `little endian` означает, что в байте с адресом, совпадающим с адресом слова находятся младшие разряды числа, которое хранится в этом слове (`big endian`, соответственно, наоборот -- в первом байте слова хранятся старшие разряды).